# convert devenv parameters to msbuild parameters

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, devenv

I am migrating a few solutions into azure devops and want to use the MSBuild Task to build them.

The are currently build using devenv with the following commands:

```
devenv.com file.vcxproj /rebuild "unittest debug" /project project_name
```

I thought I would try with

```
msbuild.exe file.vcxproj /p:Project=project_name /p:configuration="unittest debug"
```

But I am getting the error that the project does not contains the "unittest debug"

I would appreaciate any help I could get.

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `devenv` command line you are using doesn't make complete sense.

`file.vcxproj` is a C++ project. If it were a solution, e.g. `somesolution.sln`, then the `/project` switch would make sense, e.g. if `somesolution.sln` included `file.vcxproj` then the following command would build `file.vcxproj`.

```
devenv.com somesolution.sln /project file
```

Solutions and projects have a 'configuration' and a 'platform'. `"unittest debug"` looks like an attempt to specify this information but the syntax is not correct. The correct syntax is

*<configuration>*|*<platform>*

The default configuratuion values are `Debug` and `Release`.

I suspect that

`"unittest debug"`

should be

`"debug|unittest"`.

The original devenv command line can probably be rewritten as

```
devenv.com file.vcxproj /rebuild "debug|unittest"
```

The MSBuild equivalent is

```
msbuild.exe file.vcxproj /t:rebuild /p:configuration=debug;platform=unittest
```

The `/build`, `/clean`, and `/rebuild` switches on `devenv` map to MSBuild targets in the C++ project. The C++ project also expects configuration and platform as separate properties.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it tomorrow. The original devenv command works, but there are some weird stuff going on so it might be buggy

Comment: I accept that the devenv command works, but I don't why it works. I can imagine that the `/project` switch is accepted as valid by the command line parsing validation but subsequently ignored because the file is not a solution. More interesting is that `"unittest debug"` is accepted. Maybe, internal to devenv, only `unittest` is used? Debug is usually the default configuration when none is specified. But I don't know and this is just speculation.